# Python, how to return a triple?

Tags: python, string

```
   def split_3(s):
      s=s.split(".",1)
      s_left=s[0]
      s_right=s[1]
      for words in s:   
          t=len(s[0])
      return ("{s_left},{t},{s_right}").format(s_left=s_left,t=t,s_right=s_right)
      #example: split_3('this is it.another one.')
      #output='this is it,10,another one.'
      #desired output= ('this is it', 10, ' another one.')
```

*The task is to return the amount of contents in the string when the first "." appears. And then format it the way that you have the output you already see(Sentence until 1st "." , number of the contents until then, the remaining string*

*Like you see i already get the desired output, however i have to return it as a triple and i am not sure how to do that*

*I hope you can help me in this case.*

Comment: `('this is it, 10, another one.')` is _not_ a triple, it's a string with some commas in parentheses. Did you mean `('this is it', 10, 'another one.')`?

Comment: Yes i am sorry that i didnt type that correctly

Comment: The for loop doesn't do anything useful. You can just set `t = len(s[0])` once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you mean this?

```
return (s_left,t,s_right)
```

Comment: Yes , pretty much...why didnt i try the obvious one first...i'm sry im still new and thought i have to do it the "weird way"..

Comment: No worries. If that got you what you want, feel free to go ahead and accept it to close the question out.

Answer (score 1):

You can also assign to a tuple from the split, so the function becomes simpler:

```
def split_3(s):
    s_left, s_right = s.split(".", 1)
    t = len(s_left)
    return (s_left, t, s_right)
```